# Can a non-citizen claim a US lottery prize on a ticket purchased through a third party?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, lottery

I used a lottery concierge service to buy a US lottery ticket online.  I am not a US citizen.  In the unlikely event of my winning, can I claim the prize if I come to the US and have the ticket with me?  Would it be illegal in any way?

Comment: If the e-mails I frequently get are any indication then no.  You would instead have to find some kindly person that would send you their bank details and split the funds with them in return for their help.

Comment: I think the question should probably be non-resident and not non-citizen. I don't think a British citizen living in the USA will have problems, and a US citizen living in Britain _will_ have the same problems.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. Selling (and buying) remotely, or even bringing in your luggage lottery tickets cross-borders is a [Federal crime](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0086-international-lottery-scams) punishable by up to [two years in prison](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1301). Exceptions exist where there's an explicit agreement to allow that between the States which borders you're crossing (which, for the Federal border, are none).

Comment: (This is because a lottery is gambling, and gambling is illegal under Federal law when applicable, e.g., across state lines - same as how it's illegal to play online poker for money.)

Comment: I don't see how that follows. Say the service is legit and mails the physical tickets to the OP before the draw. The draw happens and the OP buys a plane ticket to the US, then appears wherever it is one appears to cash in a winning ticket. **Regardless of whether having someone buy that ticket remotely is legal or not** will the OP be able to cash the ticket? Or will the place ask for proof of residency, or in other ways interfere with the cashing of the winning ticket?

Comment: It's far from clear that getting someone else to buy your lottery tickets is equivalent to 'selling lottery tickets'. Otherwise every time someone sent their husband to pick up a tickets it would be a federal offence.

Comment: @DJClayworth corrected.

Comment: @KateGregory the service cannot both *be legit* and *mail the physical ticket*. The latter is illegal and thus contradicts the former. Even if *the ticket* is not fraudulent by itself - it was acquired illegally and thus invalidated.

Comment: @littleadv a non legit service would say they were buying you tickets and then just keep your money. A legit one would perform the illegal service for you. Illegal doesn't mean impossible or even a scam - while it's wrong to help people break the law it can still be done.

Comment: @littleadv: And the lottery commission is to know this ... how exactly? You are answering a different question to the one posed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you can't because the ticket is invalid. Whether you can fraudulently claim - of course, and you may not even be caught - but the question didn't ask whether fraudulent claims are allowed, did it?

Comment: Yes, it did. There are two parts to the question. "Can I claim" and "Would it be illegal". You answered half of it only.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Even if the seller broke the law, it does not follow legally that the buyer must have also violated the law, or that the ticket would be invalidated. Also, the page linked chiefly refers to US customers buying tickets outside the US , which is the exact inverse of the question asked.

Comment: @MSalters except that it is illegal to both sell **and** purchase. The law doesn't specify the direction of purchase. The page deals with scams where someone out of the US is scamming an American, but the law works in both directions. It is illegal to buy or sell *cross border* regardless of direction. See 18 U.S. Code § 1301

Comment: @littleadv: That's a critical addition to this answer, if not a better answer. I wasn't disputing the legality, just the pointing out that the reasoning is legally flawed.

Comment: @MSalters clarified.

Answer (score 2):

I checked California's lottery. Their claim form simply states that you must declare whether you are a citizen, US resident alien, or neither. If you're one of the first two, the California Lottery will withhold 25% for federal taxes. If you're neither, they will withhold 28%. If you do not declare one of these, they'll withhold 30%.

I don't have an easy way to grab the exact link, but the form is available on the [California Lottery website](http://www.calottery.com).

I do not know if the same information holds true for multi-state lotteries like PowerBall.

Comment: multistate lotteries are handled by the state lotteries in each state. However, the problem here is that the ticket is illegally obtained and as such is not valid.

Comment: That may be meant to cover tourists buying lottery tickets while in the USA.